# The app run perfectly in emulator but in My android device an exception is thrown

Tags: android

In my app I want to pick an image from gallery. But this app runs perfectly in emulator but in My android device an exception is thrown. The code is given below.`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgDecodableString;
ImageView imgView;



public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

}

I have also added in the manifest

```
<uses-permission

     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My device api is 19, and emulator's api is 23.

Comment: Add` requestPermissions` method .

Comment: already added it to the manifest

Comment: I meant that [Working with System Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: You can use [this library](https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher) in your code .

Comment: what exception, post the stack trace

Comment: Why are you surprised? Emulator and device use two totally different APIs. So please post the stack trace, and possibly even read it, it will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: fix it. Thanks to all. :)